# I am getting Exe_Bad_Access(code=1 address=0X38) when I am integrating the CCAvenue Payment Gate way in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, encryption, ccavenue

I followed the following steps for integrating the non-shameless `CCAvenue` GateWay

**Steps**:-

I have my merchant id and access code's(url,ip).

1. I am calling my server for getting the RSA key parameters (access_code ,order_id)

// my server already register in CCAvenue Server 
2.my server calling the Avenue for RSA key

3.my server forwarding the RSA key

4.once i got i am removing extra lines"\n ",double quotes" "--" ",and "\"

```
// removing double quates


 NSString * newReplacedString2 = [rsaKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""]; 

//removing /n in the key


  NSString * newReplacedString = [newReplacedString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];


 //removing / in the key

 NSString * newReplacedString1 = [newReplacedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```

5.and i am placing that key between

```
rsaKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n%@\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",newReplacedString1];

//*******//***//****//**//  output   //*******//***//****//**//
```

> ```
>    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>     MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuV7OdmPSutrlOE9lF3YdW4ymGn+qselCOycMk95Tobw1PcqCeAWkrnxUECpAdnHGrUKmFbEDHs3wnwzLTbfa3GvE5dvvmluug78X3RYEFQiMh1QpfS5fBfvs4WQKw7oigko3G0UwZLZFnZ4E4WKTQi4wbCgjwQJFMnMGJfFYNcoSJluVg/q8z3bVxfDOV0ZPWccmvA3bTf9YFHKCC3clscQrGf1NPnBGcBGm+s06t3EljoSmpjtyTgSiGrqBZ8TSCQxoyXxS+RkhNTigg6mqW9hIisxYYqlbzvRnCDhuqgZfmP7t65QG5raELVE7d+Ia+dgh024luZ9+vSk4Qb65DQIDAQAB
>     -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
> ```

6. I am encrypting the amount and price using CCTool

   ```
   NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"amount=%@&currency=%@",amount,currency];(2,INR)
   CCTool *ccTool = [[CCTool alloc] init];
   NSString *encVal = [ccTool encryptRSA:myRequestString key:rsaKey];
   ```

in that I am getting the **Exe_Bad_Acess** in

> RSA *rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bufio, NULL,NULL,NULL);

that rsa getting error.

[image]

how to resolve this issue.Please Help me Guys.!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi  thank you for all support, i finally resolved my issue.

once u get the rsa key from ur server you need to remove the new lines "\n",slashes "\" and double quotes"\""

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuV7OdmPSutrlOE9lF3YdW4ymGn+qselCOycMk95Tobw1PcqCeAWkrnxUECpAdnHGrUKmFbEDHs3wnwzLTbfa3GvE5dvvmluug78X3RYEFQiMh1QpfS5fBfvs4WQKw7oigko3G0UwZLZFnZ4E4WKTQi4wbCgjwQJFMnMGJfFYNcoSJluVg/q8z3bVxfDOV0ZPWccmvA3bTf9YFHKCC3clscQrGf1NPnBGcBGm+s06t3EljoSmpjtyTgSiGrqBZ8TSCQxoyXxS+RkhNTigg6mqW9hIisxYYqlbzvRnCDhuqgZfmP7t65QG5raELVE7d+Ia+dgh024luZ9+vSk4Qb65DQIDAQAB
```

Here we need to convert it into the input for the  ba64encryption format.

https://gist.github.com/superwills/5415344#file-openssl-rsa-encryption-sample-L154

u need to convert our string exactly same,
  1. Each line of "string" must be 64 characters wide.
  2.it must be terminated with a newline

I am updating my Code.For Me its Working Fine.

```
  NSString *rsaKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

//            NSString *rsaKey = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

```
        NSLog(@"%@",rsaKey);
```

//            rsaKey = [rsaKey stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
//            NSLog(@"%@",rsaKey);

```
        // removing double quates
        NSString * newReplacedString2 = [rsaKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

        NSLog(@"%@",rsaKey);

        //removing \n in the key
        NSString * newReplacedString = [newReplacedString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];

        NSLog(@"%@",rsaKey);


        //removing \ in the key
        NSString * newReplacedString1 = [newReplacedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"%@",newReplacedString1);


        NSString * abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", newReplacedString1];
        NSMutableString *sss=[NSMutableString new];
        int j=(int)([abc length]/63);
        for (int i=0; i<=j; i++) {
            int k= i*63;
            NSString * newString;
            if (i != j) {
                newString = [abc substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(k,63)];
                NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)newString.length);
                newString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newString];
            }else{
                newString = [abc substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(k,[abc length]-k)];
                NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)newString.length);
                if (newString.length !=0)
                    newString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newString];
            }
            if (newString.length !=0)
                [sss appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",newString]];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",sss);


        rsaKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n%@-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",sss];
        NSLog(@"%@",rsaKey);

        //Encrypting Card Details
            NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"amount=%@&currency=%@",amount,currency];
            CCTool *ccTool = [[CCTool alloc] init];


        NSLog(@"emcrpted data  skfjsf jakdfhjklfhjk%@",[ccTool encryptRSA:myRequestString key:rsaKey]);






            Happy Coding. :)
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be an issue with the return key you are getting from server. Seems that server is not configured correctly here. We had the same problem. Just send this error report to this email:      service@ccavenue.com

Its CCAvenue technical support email. You can ask for their contact number for technical support and it will be quick for any technical question you might have while integration.

Comment: Gokilani    hi i already sent my report/Users/hmw-pc1/Downloads/IOS_RSAFormat.txt

Comment: Hi  i already sent the report to them they are  mentation this formate https://gist.githubusercontent.com/naveen527/ede0cdd698d594dd2ec7890bb137e6bc/raw/2589fe7560b26a601cbb294b5971605a53a40702/rsa%2520formate

Comment: i done same but getting same problem:( @Bhumi Goklani

Comment: bhumi i will forward my code can u check it ... please , i tried all methods ,but i did't get the result .

Comment: Ok. Please send me dropbox link.
I can give it a try.

Comment: TQ , i got the solution for my issue. @Bhumi

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message can be seen that a memory leak occurred.

I have encountered similar mistakes.

You can try my method.

Xcode -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics -> select Address Sanitizer

Run your project.

Comment: No @Huber J   no change in output :(

Comment: Apply too much memory space, the release of the time did not release completely.

Comment: You should check it, I have encountered such a mistake.